# How to set X-Frame-Options Allow-From in nginx correctly

Tags: nginx, cross-domain, content-security-policy, x-frame-options

Im trying to set the ALLOWED-FROM in Nginx but all settings I tried so far resulted in the following Chrome error:
`Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'https://domain.com/#/register': 'ALLOW-FROM domain.com' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored.`

This options I tried are those: (tried also with FQDN with `https://` prefix)

```
  add_header X-Frame-Options "Allow-From domain.com"; 
  add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM domain.com"; 
  add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM: domain.com";
  add_header X-Frame-Options "Allow-From: domain.com";
  add_header X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM "domain.com";
  add_header X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM domain.com;
```

Comment: Chrome does not support `allow-from`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 37, accepted):

in Chrome and Safari you need to use **Content-Security-Policy**

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors domain.com
```

You can check more details on this site:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives

Comment: That is not a valid nginx directive. The actual directive would be `add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors domain.com";`.

Answer (score 29):

Some older browser do not support Content Security Policy so the correct syntax is

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM domain.com";
```

and the new version of browsers support Content Security Policy

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors domain.com";
```

You should use both the headers so as to ensure support in all the browser

To know more browser support for X-Frame-Options and Content Security Policy(CSP browser support data is outdated as written on 12/19/2017. Currently all major browser support CSP):
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet